# "basename: missing operand" on docker terminal

Tags: bash, docker, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I wanted to use the machine learning scripts presented in this link: https://idealo.github.io/image-quality-assessment/. The link for the github repository is https://github.com/idealo/image-quality-assessment. I am using a Windows 10 Home machine with Docker toolbox. I executed the following command provided in the above link in the docker terminal.

`bash ./predict \ --docker-image nima-cpu \ --base-model-name MobileNet \ --weights-file $(pwd)/models/MobileNet/weights_mobilenet_technical_0.11.hdf5 \ --image-source $(pwd)/src/tests/test_images/42039.jpg`

The above command is expected to generate a numerical prediction value as the output for the input image `42039.jpg` by passing it through a trained convolutional network model.

But I am getting the following error,

```
basename: missing operand
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
```

The contents of the predict file are as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# parse arguments
POSITIONAL=()
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
do
key="$1"

case $key in
    --docker-image)
    DOCKER_IMAGE="$2"
    shift # past argument
    shift # past value
    ;;
    --base-model-name)
    BASE_MODEL_NAME="$2"
    shift # past argument
    shift # past value
    ;;
    --weights-file)
    WEIGHTS_FILE="$2"
    shift # past argument
    shift # past value
    ;;
    --image-source)
    IMAGE_SOURCE="$2"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
    *)    # unknown option
    POSITIONAL+=("$1") # save it in an array for later
    shift # past argument
    ;;
esac
done


BASENAME_IS=`basename $IMAGE_SOURCE`

# run predictions
DOCKER_RUN="docker run
  --entrypoint entrypoints/entrypoint.predict.cpu.sh \
  -v "$IMAGE_SOURCE":/src/$BASENAME_IS
  -v "$WEIGHTS_FILE":/src/weights.hdf5
  $DOCKER_IMAGE $BASE_MODEL_NAME /src/weights.hdf5 /src/$BASENAME_IS"

eval $DOCKER_RUN
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is `basename` called? Within `predict`? If we can't see it, there's no way to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Yes, basename is used within predict. The link for the github repo containing all the files: [Github repository](https://github.com/idealo/image-quality-assessment/)

Comment: Your question should be self-contained, you should extract the relevant parts of the script in a way that reproduces your error (see [mcve]).

Comment: Smells like `$IMAGE_SOURCE` is empty. BTW, `$(pwd)` is slow to run, because every time you use `$(...)` it forks off a new copy of the shell to run the code in `...`; use `$PWD` instead.

Comment: (And use names with at least one lower-case character for your own variables; all-caps names are used for variables set by or meaningful to the shell itself, whereas lowercase names are guaranteed not to cause a compliant shell to have unexpected behaviors, as defined by the standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- read that document keeping in mind that environment variables and regular shell variables share a single namespace).